# Calculating column value in current row of Spark Dataframe based on the calculated value of a column in previous row using java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

Let's say I have static value as 10000

Now, I have a Dataframe like below

| Col A | Col B |
| --- | --- |
| A | 500 |
| S | 100 |
| A | 1000 |
| S | 100 |

With Transformation I want it like below

| Col A | Col B | Col C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 500 | 10500 |
| S | 100 | 10400 |
| A | 1000 | 11400 |
| S | 100 | 11300 |

The thing works by the details provided below

- For the first row based on **Col A** value (***A*** for add and ***S*** for subtract) I am adding value **Col B** value with static value to get **Col C** value
- From next row onward based on **Col A** value I am adding or subtracting **Col B** value with **Col C** value of previous row.

I was trying to find out **Col A** value using spark functions class but haven't found anything. Please help me to form the logic.